# How to fill cells in the Excel with serie, range or similar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

How I fill selected region (column) with needed numbers?

I have very long columns, so I am not able to use that small rectangle in the bottom-right-corner and drag it down (autofill or how to name it).

I must select the all column region first and then - then I would need to say to Excel, how to fill it.
This was normally possible to do in the previous versions of Excel.
Where can I find it in the last version(s) of the desktop Excel? (probably is version 2019, but this Excel is missing "About", so I don't now what the exact version is on this comp).

Comment: try double clicking on the small rectangle...

Comment: Thank you, @gns100, it is not exactly, what I am looking for, but in some cases it will be very sufficient workaround. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to create a custom list go to File -> Options -> Advance... scroll down to the general section. There should be a button to `Edit Custom Lists...`. Don't ask me why MS decided that was the place to put this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the "Fill" option, it should be under the "Home" tab of your ribbon.

If it is not there already, add it by right-clicking on the toolbar, select "Customise the Ribbon" then select from the options.
If it is already in the ribbon it should look like this:

[image]

If you need to add it you need to find this:

[image]

Then highlight the range and select the required type of fill.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the range, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to fill **D**own

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I probably hadn't described problem accurately - I mean not with one number, but with bunch of different numbers, which have some pattern (e.g. like "series" in mathematics).